# dinamically change style of a div in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i want to change the color of an element inside my angular app by  using dynamic class,
here is my code , its works but not as expected, i have to reload the page before the color of my element change . there is my code .
i hope you can help me
thanks you in advance

```html
<div class="w-full h-10 flex items-center px-4 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200" [class]="file.id == id.id ? 'bg-blue-100' : '' " (click)="navigate(file.id)">
                        {{ file.id }} 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the use of `ngClass` - e.g.

```
  <p>Passing a configuration object:</p>
  <button [ngClass]="{ btn:true, 'btn-primary':true }">
    Button
  </button>
```

Example is from here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/

Answer (score -2):

you can inject ChangeDetectorRef and force angular to check for changes

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

in your function

```
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```